# Not seeing the log output from testing Service

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso, servicetestcase

I have a working Service (*I know it works, because I manually tested*).  However, I am trying to build JUnit/Espresso test case for it. Though Android Studio told me that the test "passed, " but I don't see the effect from invoking the service.  I tried to put some debugging message ,"*Starting the service*", but **I don't see any of the log message on the console.

Does anyone have any idea?  Thanks!

```
private static StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();

@Test
public void testWithoutLocation(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(), SendMessage.class);

    intent.putExtra(BaseService.TAG_PERSON_ID, "ABCD");
    intent.putExtra(BaseService.TAG_MESSAGE_ID, "12345");

    try {
        log.append("Starting the service");
        oServiceTestRule.startService(intent);


    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail("TimeoutException caught");
    }

}
```

Comment: You did not call to show the `log`. Try `Log.d(TAG, log.toString());` in `try` block

Comment: Steve...I tried the Log.d, but no lock.

Comment: is this a maven project?

Answer (score 0):

With your current `snip`, I saw only one issue that you forget to show the `log`. So, make sure your test is run (passed as you said) and your `logcat` is activated (and [select `verbose` level](https://developer.android.com/images/tools/as-ddmslog.png)). So, try to change this:

```
try {
        log.append("Starting the service");
        oServiceTestRule.startService(intent);
        Log.d("YOUR_TAG", "testWithoutLocation: " + log.toString())

    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail("TimeoutException caught");
    }
```

If it's still not working, try to restart `logcat` or add more information.

Comment: Does this help to answer you question?